# Flex 4 - How to Enable/Disable certain tabs in tabBar

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, tabbar

Is there a way to Enable and Disable specific tabs in a tabBar?  I found one example using a VBox within the ViewStack but I'm using NavigatorContent.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Can you point to the example you found already? Also some code sample would be nice.  Sounds like your mixing MX and Spark but I'm not sure exactly how and it would be helpful to answering the question, also there may be an easier solution using the spark ButtonBar (I actually happened to just be toying with this at the moment and decided to pop open stack overflow)

Comment: Similar question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539000/flex-4-tabbar-disable-tab

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, if you disable the NavigatorContent with `enable="false", it will disable the tab as well.

The other way of doing it is by sending the ButtonTabBar a custom list of objects which has an 'enabled' property to it, then create a custom button item renderer that enables/disables when the data changes.

Comment: in Flex 4 it only disables the NavigationContent section, not the tab of the tabBar.

Comment: Oh right, that was TabNavigator, not ViewStack with ButtonTabBar.  My bad.  Then I would use the item renderer approach.  The data that you would get back should be the actual NavigatorContent. Just need to bind the enabled property of the data to your item renderer's enabled property.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for, I use this to disable buttons in the TabbedViewNavigatorApplication TabBar.

```
    ButtonBarButton(this.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.dataGroup.getElementAt(0)).enabled = false;
    ButtonBarButton(this.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.dataGroup.getElementAt(1)).enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at [the Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/650960) -

I created a new TabBar skin (imaginatively named "TabBarSkinWithDisabledTabs").
In it, I changed

```
<s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="spark.skins.spark.TabBarButtonSkin" />
```

to `<s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="spark.skins.spark.TabBarButtonSkin" enabled="{data.enabled}" />`

It works for me (Flex 4.5).

Main code:

```
    <s:TabBar id="theTabBar" change="theTabBar_changeHandler(event)" cornerRadius="4"
          dataProvider="{vwStack}" skinClass="skins.TabBarWithDisabledTab"/>
<mx:ViewStack id="vwStack" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="tab1">
        <!-- irrelevant content here -->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="tab2">
        <!-- irrelevant content here -->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="tab3" enabled="false">
        <!-- irrelevant content here -->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Answer (score -1):

i have togglebuttonbar (flex3),i wanted to do the same thing which u r asking for

> ButtonBarButton(togbar.getChildAt(0)).enabled
>   = true; ButtonBarButton(togbar.getChildAt(1)).enabled
>   = true; ButtonBarButton(togbar.getChildAt(2)).enabled
>   = false;

where togbar is the "id" of the togglebuttonbar, so in this way you can do whtever u want to do with buttons, 
i hope this will help

Ankur

Comment: here ma togglebuttonbar had three buttons,

Comment: ryt, n e ways, hav a gr8 time brother